# How to dismiss AlertIOS

Tags: react-native

How can I dismiss the AlertIOS prompt? See my example code. The problem is, when I push the "Cancel" button, the "this.newFile()" function is called. Any ideas how to fix this.

```
newFilePrompt: function() {
    AlertIOS.prompt(
        'New File',
        'new file',
        [
            {text: 'Cancel'},
            {text: 'Create', onPress: this.newFile()},
        ]
    );
},

newFile: function() {
    alert("new file");
},
```

Also interesting: If I change the code to:

```
newFilePrompt: function() {
    AlertIOS.prompt(
        'New File',
        'new file',
        [
            {text: 'Cancel', onPress: this.cancel()},
            {text: 'Create', onPress: this.newFile()},
        ]
    );
},

cancel: function() {
    alert("irgendwas");
},

newFile: function() {
    alert("new file");
},
```

both functions are called everytime, regardless of which button is pressed. At first the "new file" alert appears and after submitting the alert, the "irgendwas" alert appears.

Comment: check out this example, it might help you https://rnplay.org/apps/l3Zi2g?route=AlertIOS&file=AlertIOSExample.js

Comment: Thanks. But I know this example and it is not helpful for my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a solution. I changed

```
onPress: this.cancel()
```

to

```
onPress: () => this.cancel()
```

React Native is more trial and error than everything else. Or a quiz game :)

Comment: This is not really React specific. When attaching an event handler (in virtually any language), you pass the reference to the function to call, like `onPress: this.cancel`.

Including the brackets means the function fires right away (the alert probably freezes the event loop though), and the return value (undefined in this case) will be attached to the `onPress` event. Wrapping your function call in another function is a bit devious.